# Can't add categories

Tags: category, admin

[image]I have a complex problem. I want to add more categories to my website, but an orange box appears. Does anyone know what to do?

I have been surving over the internet and some pages tell me to re-instlal the ADMINHTML + ADMIN on my FTP. I did, but still it''s not working.All help is welcome[image]

Comment: Did you install any modules before this happened or change anything?

Comment: i only added one module named  image attribute

Comment: Which module is that and might it have something to do with the categories

Comment: sander am new to this let me know what to do now? This is the name of that module "magento-attribute-option-image-master"

Comment: We need a lot more info to help you. My best guess is that the module you installed is causing this. To find out please uninstall the module and check if the error persists

Comment: what info you need and how can i uninstall this module?

Comment: Error logs, some code that might cause this. And to uninstall either remove all files or contact the developer about instructions

Comment: sander check the error log i attach in the questions and comment all that module files but error is still there

Comment: Please check with your hosting provider if Imagick is installed correctly on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not complete answer, but I will give a try since I had same problem before.

I believe it's your `index.php` file. After customizing the file, I was getting this issue.

You can see your footer is not loaded yet, so there are loads of other files are missing. That's why it is looking bit of messed up and not letting you do anything.

Please find the fresh file and replace with yours. Also make backup before replacing it.

Comment: Adarsh can you please tell me where it is that file named "index.php"

Comment: In your root folder.

Comment: Adarsh footer is loaded already. This is not shown in the above screen shot

Comment: login to your ftp and then go to root folder that means your all magento folders are placed. You will find some other folders like `app, js, lib, skin` etc.